# How would you (incrementally) backup KVM VMs based on LVM storage?

Tags: backup, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, lvm, hypervisor

I'm running a set of KVM hypervisors on LVM storage (unfortunately I can't use QCOW2, because the virtualization platform I'm using is strictly LVM-based).

The virtualization platform has a very poor backup support, so I wrote a series of scripts which perform LVM snapshots, grab the image with qemu-image, compress and store it on a separate storage.

My scripts work well enough, but with increasing number of VMs and data to manage are beginning to show their limits.

Can someone suggest me a free or commercial solution to have the work done well?
This is what I'm doing now and what I need to do:

- scheduled backups
- daily and weekly rotation and retention
- backup saved on external storage
- restore system
- (extra points for incremental backup)

The VMs are both Linux and Windows, so I can't rely on the internal filesystem.

I don't *need* a web UI or other frills, CLI management is enough.

Answer (score 4):

Use Veeam agent-based VM backup. Before Veeam would re-publish  their Nutanix AHV backup as a “generic” KVM VM backup.